# How to seperate repeat pattern in a line using sed or awk, and save them to lines?

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I am having a lot of files consisting a very long line (size unknown), in a pattern

```
[ ["11/24/19","5.34","2.38",..."9.35"], 
["11/23/19","4.36","9.29",..."8.35"], [...], [...], [...] ]
```

I want to separate the line into pieces, looks like the following:

```
"11/24/19","5.34","2.38",..."9.35"
"11/23/19","4.36","9.29",..."8.35"
...
```

A beginner for `sed` or `awk`, trying for several hours with no luck. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, replace `],` with a newline. Then, remove all the square brackets.

```
sed 's/],/\n/g;s/[][]//g'
```